# Converting a dateTime Object to string

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having trouble converting a date Time object to a string, so I can pass it through a MySQLi prepared statement which specifies data types.

The error I'm receiving is:

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

The line this error refers to is the execution of my prepared statement. I still receive this error despite many attempts at converting the Object to a string. Below I will paste the main 3 ways I've tried to tackle this issue.

## 1 - Using a casting operator:

```
$total_hours_calc = $time_diff->format('%h') + ($time_diff->format('%i'))/60;
$total_hours = (string)$total_hours_calc;
```

## 2 - Using Print_r:

```
$total_hours_calc = $time_diff->format('%h') + ($time_diff->format('%i'))/60;
$total_hours = print_r($total_hours_calc, true)
```

## 3 - Concatenation workaround:

```
$total_hours_calc = $time_diff->format('%h') + ($time_diff->format('%i'))/60;
$total_hours = $total_hours_calc . "";
```

All these attempts return the error stated at the beginning of this question.

Any help, solutions or magic PHP functions unknown to those who have yet to achieve a black belt in the art of PHP - are greatly appreciated.

## [Requested] The Prepared statement -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO shift ".
       "(uniqueid, shift_date, start_time, end_time, total_hours, rate_of_pay, addedBy, paidRate, totalPaid) ".
       "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $uniqueid, $shift_date, $start_time, $end_time, $total_hours, $rate_of_pay, $addedBy, $paidRate, $totalPaid); 
$stmt->execute();
```

The line referred to in all errors is: `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: What are you trying to do? How do you initialize `$time_diff`?

Comment: show these lines: _The line this error refers to is the execution of my prepared statement._

Comment: $time_diff is simply a `date_diff` of 2 times. I'm simply trying to convert the dateTime object to a string so it can be stored in database using MySQLi prepared statement. I can't store it as an integer as it can have a decimal point, so I need to store it as a string.

Comment: @Danieloplata: Can you show us the code you're using? With some example date time strings.

Comment: as from this: `$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $uniqueid, $shift_date, $start_time, $end_time, $total_hours, $rate_of_pay, $addedBy, $paidRate, $totalPaid);` I assume that there are at least three vars looking like a DateTime Object: `$shift_date`, `$start_time` and  `$end_time`. Did you check all of them or how do you know its related to `$total_hours`?

Comment: The others are created by using datepickers/timepickers, so they are posted as a string rather than a dateTime object. The only dateTime object in the code is $total_hours.

Comment: @Danieloplata: You want to show the inserted values

Comment: You are looking for the error at wrong place. `$total_hours = (string)$total_hours_calc;` converts to a string, so does concatenation. The error is about some other variable.

Comment: The line `$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $uniqueid, $shift_date...)` contains about 10 variables. MySQL driver could be complaining about any of those variable.

Comment: @Danieloplata, do a `var_dump(array($uniqueid, $shift_date, $start_time, $end_time, $total_hours, $rate_of_pay, $addedBy, $paidRate, $totalPaid))` and put the output here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the php documentation DateTime does not natively implement the __toString() method, which explains the exceptions you keep getting. You may extend DateTime and implement __toString yourself, provided you are using php 5.2 or later.

```
class DateTimeExt extends DateTime
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
}
```

Replace all instances of DateTime used in the bind_param call with DateTimeExt and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking in the wrong place by focusing on `$total_hours`, which is a already a string (or an integer that can be converted to a string)

In [the snippet you linked](https://eval.in/141239), you're changing the variables `$start_time` and `$end_time` from strings to `DateTime` objects, which would throw the indicated errors when you later try to use them in the prepared statement.
See this snippet, which prints the diff value correctly, but then errors when printing the DateTime object `$start_time`: https://eval.in/145608

I can think of two possible resolutions:

---

Use another variable for the string value of `$start_time` and `$end_time` in the prepared statement

```
$start_time = "9:00";
$end_time = "17:30";

$start_time = new DateTime($start_time);
$end_time = new DateTime($end_time);
$time_diff = date_diff($start_time,$end_time);

$start_time_string = $start_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_time_string = $end_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $uniqueid, $shift_date, $start_time_string, $end_time_string, $total_hours, $rate_of_pay, $addedBy, $paidRate, $totalPaid);
```

---

Create a subclass of `DateTime` that implements [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring), and utilize it instead.

```
class DateTimeDb extends DateTime {
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  }
}

$start_time = "9:00";
$end_time = "17:30";

$start_time = new DateTimeDb($start_time);
$end_time = new DateTimeDb($end_time);
$time_diff = date_diff($start_time,$end_time);

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $uniqueid, $shift_date, $start_time, $end_time, $total_hours, $rate_of_pay, $addedBy, $paidRate, $totalPaid);
```

Comment: Second resolution clears the issue, my apologies for error in the snippet. The `$start_time` and `$end_time` variables do not get overwritten in my code, but get assigned to new variables. Not sure why your answer got downvoted, but I will upvote as your answer contains the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add two strings

```
  $total_hours_calc = intval($time_diff->format('%h'),10) + intval($time_diff->format('%i'),10)/60;
```

Comment: He's not trying to concatenate them. They're just numbers, so it should work just fine.

Comment: @Amal again: you can't _add_ two strings. `...format(..` returns a string.

Comment: @AxelAmthor: So what? PHP is loosely typed. It works just fine. See [this demo](https://eval.in/141202).

Comment: @Danieloplata: I have tried like below it is returning no of hours. <?php

$time_diff = (new DateTime('2014-04-20 03:02:11'))->diff(new DateTime('now'));

echo $total_hours_calc = intval($time_diff->format('%h'),10) + intval($time_diff->format('%i'),10)/60;                           So what is your exact requierement?

Comment: The code to return the no. of hours is fine, I'm trying to convert it to a string for storage in database.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the values to INT before summing them

```
$total_hours_calc = (int)$time_diff->format('%h') + ((int)$time_diff->format('%i'))/60;
```

And quote the result date as string, before using it

```
$total_hours = "'".$total_hours_calc."'";
```

There may be a better way to quote the last value.. depending on your implementation,
but  `$int .""` is usually not enough;

Comment: Unfortunately this still returns the error: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

Comment: on which row? you probably get the error from some other place of the code. can you please paste the exact line  from the error ?

Comment: The error comes from the line executing the prepared statement - see the updated question.

Comment: try to replace  `$shift_date`, `$start_time`, `$end_time`, `$total_hours` with dummy value like '01.01.2014' as string, and see which one is making the problem.

Comment: @ramsai there are no errors with the query (it fails before even executed), but one of the assigned variables is an object and not a string as expected.

Comment: The problem value is `$total_hours`, which is still an object despite my efforts to convert it to a string. Apologies I thought my question made it clear that this was the issue. All the other variables are created as strings and the statement executes without error if `$total_hours` is removed.

Comment: @Danieloplata the code samples you provided look OK. try to print `$total_hours` just before the `bind_params` it may hint what is wrong. Otherwise review the other parts of the code for any redeclaration or something.

Comment: @d.raev Printing `$total_hours` before the `bind_params` returns `'7.5'`

Comment: OK, do you use any loop (inserting multiple rows) or if condition ?
may be in there is a case where `$total_hours` get different assigment, for example if `$time_diff` is wrong/notset.

Comment: Performed a find in files search and can confirm the code posted here is the only instance of `$total_hours`. This may interest you, as it is confusing me - https://eval.in/141239 this function should be returning an error if `$total_hours` is not a string, however as it is encased in single quotes in the output as opposed to the `$testString`, I believe the prepared statement is not recognizing it as a string. The function itself seems to accept the `'8.5'` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format method of the DateTime class :

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If format fails , it will return FALSE :

```
if ($result) { // OK
   echo $result;
} 
else { // if format failed
  echo "Unknown Time";
}
```